# Android escape JavaScript String

Tags: javascript, android, string, variables

I'm appending a JavaScript to an HTML file using android. I have this part:

```
String JavaScriptStr = "this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');";
```

Eclipse gives me an error saying:

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n, etc...)
```

How do I escape that JS string? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape `\`, Try

```
String JavaScriptStr = "this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\\.]/g,'');";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a class called StringEscapeUtils in common langs api, which will provide you several methods like escapeHTML and escapeJavascript to escape html and javascript respectively. Otherswise you can also use solution suggested by xdazz.