# javascript to string in android

Tags: javascript, android, string

I have a code snippet now I want to convert it to string. unable to find any solution. How can I do it?

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;">
        <p>
            <a href="tel:133300">
                <img src="http://www.biznessapps.com/imghost/0/52/104345/NewcastleTaxis.jpg" alt="" width="257" height="108" />
            </a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong>
                <span style="font-size: small; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">Taxi Services</span>
            </strong><br />
            <span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: small;">Ring for a taxi and share the fare with a friend</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: small;"><a href="tel:133300">Call 133 300</a></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: small;">Taxis only pick up from the following secure ranks between 12am to 5am.</span><br />
            <span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: small;">&bull; Kent Hotel and Exchange Hotel (Beaumont St), Hamilton</span><br />
            <span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: small;">&bull; King St Hotel (corner of King and Steel St), Newcastle</span><br />
            <span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: small;">&bull; Fanny&rsquo;s (Centenary Rd), Newcastle</span><br />
            <span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: small;">&bull; The Brewery (Wharf Rd), Newcastle</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: small;">For more information visit <a href="http://www.newcastletaxis.com.au" target="_blank">www.newcastletaxis.com.au</a></span>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is this javascript ?

Comment: Your code doesn't have any javascript.

Comment: Please go through the link it may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073622/android-escape-javascript-string

Comment: sorry it was my mistake but i want to store that code in string .. help me

Comment: That's only HTML, you know.

Comment: ya... thanks but now how to convert it into string

Comment: First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow! Second, it isn't clear what you want to do. What have you tried?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what I understand of this is that you want something like this:

`var html = 'put here your code';`

Answer (score 1):

First off, the code you posted isn’t Javascript; it’s HTML (and it doesn’t contain any Javascript).

Second, you don’t provide any context to your question, nor do you frankly ask a question. Please provide some useful information in order to get an answer:

- What is it that you’re trying to do?
- What specific problem are you trying to solve?
- What programming language are you using?
- What have you tried to do so far, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?
- Where does that HTML come from (a file, a database, a web server)?  Where does it need to go?

Comment: +1 for actually helping him to ask a question (and for the sake of your 4k)